# Why wont my ListView onListItemClick return the ListView as a text value?

Tags: android

I apologize if this is total newb on my behalf.  I am brand new to android programming and I am frustrated as hell!  I have looked and tried so many examples on this but they all seem to be yielding the same result.

The bottom line is... i have a listview of contact names.  when i click on a name I want the toast to repeat their name.  But instead of toasting their name I keep getting values like "android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@40571e90" where I would expect to see "John Smith"

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ContactListOne extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_list_one);
        populateContactListOne();
   }

    private Cursor getContacts()
    {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        return managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    }

    private void populateContactListOne() {
        Cursor cursor = getContacts();
        //Build adapter with contact info

        String[] fields = new String[] {

                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        int[] to = new int[]{

                R.id.contactname
        };

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_list_one_rows, cursor, fields, to);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        String keyword =  getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString();

        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here are my 2 xml layouts:

contact_list_one:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@android:id/list"

                  />



    </LinearLayout>
```

contact_list_one_rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



                   <TextView 
                  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                  android:id="@+id/contactname"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:padding="7dip"
                  >
                  </TextView>
```

----------------------------------update------------------------------------------

I am not sure how clean this is... or exactly why it works differently.  But i found an example somewhere on the web it was outdated using an old version of android... but it seems to work.    Here is how I changed my code, by all means if someone can explain to me why this works differently I would love the explanation :)

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class ContactListOne extends ListActivity {

    private static final int NEW_RULE_CONTACT=1;

    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    private RulesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    private ListView wtf;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_list_one);
        mDbHelper = new RulesDbAdapter(this);



        mDbHelper.open();

        // Obtain handles to UI objects



      Cursor cursor = getContacts();
        //Build adapter with contact info



        String[] fields = new String[] {

                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        int[] to = new int[]{

                R.id.contactname
        };

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_list_one_rows, cursor, fields, to);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    private Cursor getContacts()
    {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        String notInList = mDbHelper.createContactNotInList();



        String selection =  ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY + notInList ;


        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";


        return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        String selection = cursor.getString(1);
        Toast.makeText(this, selection,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   



    }



}
```

Comment: if my answer didnt work show me `R.layout.contact_list_one_rows`

Comment: What is the purpose of the second xml layout????

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.  I get the same text toast. android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@40571e90

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
     String keyword =  ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.contactname)).getText();
     Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.  it actually required me to do this: 

String keyword =  (String) ((TextView)getListAdapter().getItem(position)).getText();
      Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

I had to import TextView and then when i ran it I got a force quit message?

Answer (score 0):

What android display is right, you are actually printing a whole cursor row, not only the column that interest you. And, as most objects in java, by default, the string representation of this object, that is, what toString returns, is the memory address of your object in the JVM.

Try using the method `public void setStringConversionColumn (int stringConversionColumn)` of your cursor with param 1 or 2 (I never remember if columns are 0 based as with jdbc). Then to get the string for this value, you could use

```
CharSequence selection = convertToString(cursor);
```

-- UPDATE

```
//somewhere in onCreate
cursor.setStringConversionColumn ( 0 or 1 );

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  //for that you will need to define cursor as a data member
  CharSequence selection = convertToString(cursor);
  Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: I am sorry, I am both new to Java and programming on the android.  I am not sure that I follow exactly what you are suggesting.  could you mock up how you would write the code?

Comment: Does this work ? Print out stuff like selection to see what happens.

Comment: Sorry I must be pretty thick...  But when I just dont follow the code above.   my cursor is in the private void populateContactListOne().  so i tried putting the cursor.setSTringConversion(0) there and it changed the code to this: ((SimpleCursorAdapter) cursor).setStringConversionColumn (0);  but then when i try to apply the   CharSequence selection = convertToString(cursor);
  Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
I cant reference the cursor anymore as its not a variable available to the entire activity.  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please declare Cursor cursor as a data member. Still initialize it inside popuate, but declare it as a field.

Comment: Did i do what you asked on my updated code?  because it is working :)